# BM25 implementation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I've hit a stump, while trying to implement the BM25 algorithm in SQL Server 2008 R2. I know that SQL Server includes the Full-Text Search option, which already implements a variant of BM25, but I would like to do some tests and since the FTS procedures are non-editable (as far as I know), I've decided to implement it myself.

I have two tables, TF (term frequency) and DF (document frequency) with the following structures:

**TF**

*Note: the weight column denotes importance of the word (it is usually 1)

```
ID | Term | DocumentID | Count | Weight*
```

**DF**

```
ID | Term | Count
```

The TF table contains the relationship between a term and a document; that is, the frequency of the term in a document. The DF table contains information about how many documents contain a term. Using these two tables I would now like to compute BM25 similarity values between two documents (one document acts as a query) according to the formula in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25). The tables TF and DF translate to functions f(q, D) and n(q) respectively:

[image]

[image]

I would like the result to be in this format:

```
DocumentA_ID | DocumentB_ID | BM25_Value
```

Here is some code that I have up to now:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BM25]
-- default parameters k => [1.2 - 2.0], b => [0.0 - 1.0]
    @K1 FLOAT = 1.2,
    @B FLOAT = 0.75
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @N FLOAT;
    DECLARE @AVGDL FLOAT;

    -- number of all documents
    SELECT @N = CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)
    FROM FullDocument;

    -- average length of documents (in words)
    SELECT @AVGDL = AVG(Length) 
    FROM (
        SELECT  DocumentID, 
                CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) AS Length 
        FROM TF 
        GROUP BY DocumentID 
    ) A;

    -- BM25 implementation  
--  SELECT  TF.Term, 
--          TF.DocumentID, 
--          C.DocumentLength, 
--          LOG((@N - DF.Count + 0.5)/(DF.Count + 0.5)) * (TF.Count * (@K1 + 1))/(TF.Count + @K1 * (1 - @B + @B * (C.DocumentLength / @AVGDL))) AS BM25, 
--          Weight
--  FROM TF 
--  INNER JOIN DF ON TF.Term = DF.Term
--  INNER JOIN (
--      SELECT  DocumentID, 
--              COUNT(*) AS DocumentLength 
--      FROM TF 
--      GROUP BY DocumentID
--  ) C ON TF.DocumentID = C.DocumentID
END
```

I'm having trouble constructing the query in the last section (BM25 implementation) to get the desired result format. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reposted this question on DBA.SE, but in the end I managed to solve it myself. Here is the link to the DBA.SE question, where I also added the solution to the problem.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/bm25-full-text-search-implementation-in-sql-server/42215#42215